# Prestashop 1.7 - Mail::Send in external php file

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to use the **Prestashop** '**Mail::Send**' functionality in a PHP script that I am creating for a **CRON** task.

I have already composed the email template but I am not sure on how and which files I need to include for me to be able to use the class outside of Prestashop context.

At the moment I have tried including the **Mail.php** file located in **/classes** folder but I receive the following error message: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ObjectModel' not found in......"

Do I somehow need to include ObjectModel or is there a better way to do this? The reason I want to use the 'Mail::Send' class is so that I can use the email templating engine.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be that you write your own little module that lives _inside_ the PrestaShop setup, and have it provide an endpoint URL that it can be called by to have its functionality triggered from the outside (cron job.)

Comment: try to include /config/config.inc.php and then /init.php within your php file. be sure to use the right path to both files above